# Creating different user profiles

Tags: java, android

I am creating a game app where you need the ability to be able to create profiles for other players and store them on your phone. I have been looking around for help, but I can't seem to find any tutorial or help for this. Does anyone know which aspect of java I need to research and learn about? I have seen that it might be to do with App-specific files but I'm not sure if that is the right thing.

Comment: You're not looking for files. Try databases

Comment: Ah yep that seems to be what I need to look into. Thank you!

Comment: Firebase allows you to login by email/password or other social networking sites. Otherwise locally it's sqlite and you have to design your database schemas around user information yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store user information in files (XML / JSON format). You can use the database too - Android supports SQLite (SQLlite database is stored as single file). Android creates files in private folder, other applications cannot access them.

More informations about files:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Example of usage of SQLite:
https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite

**Remember not to store user sensitive data in plaintext.**

Comment: Yep after looking around it is SQLite that I need. Thank you.